# Is it neccessary that left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
public String toString() {    
    return " Recipient:"+  this.toString(this.getRecipient()) +
               " CC:"+ this.toString
                           (
                       if(this.getCC()==null)
                       {
                           getCC() = "";
                       }
                           ) +
               " Subject:"+this.getSubject() +
               " Body:"+ this.getBody() +
               " files:"+ this.getFiles();        
}
```

I am having this error in:

getCC() = "";   <--------- Here.

Do you know why is this happening?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't assign an expression to a method call.

Comment: Well, because "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Comment: You also can't use an `if` statement within another expression like this... perhaps you were looking for the conditional `?:` operator?

Comment: @JonSkeet except it's an argument to `toString()` o_O

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, I suspect that all the calls to `toString(expression)` should probably be replaced with just `expression` anyway. It's very hard to tell what the OP is actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonSkeet or whether `toString(x)` is an overloaded helper class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to the return of a method. You also can't place an expression inside a method which takes no arguments.  What you appear to have intended was to use a variable.

```
String cc = getCC();
if (cc == null) cc = "";
return ... " CC:" + cc + ...
```